# What algebraic formula would this look like for a leveling points system?

Tags: algorithm, math, formula

You're killing an online player for 4 points per kill. The higher level room you are in, the more points you are rewarded per kill.

Level 1 through 2 would be considered 4 points by default.

Would would the formula look like for this kind of points rewarding system?

Room Level 1 through 2 += 4 points per kill

Room Level 3 through 5 += 5 points per kill

Room Level 6 through 8 += 6 points per kill

Room Level 9 through 11 += 7 points per kill

Room Level 12 through 14 += 8 points per kill

Room Level 15 through 17 += 9 points per kill

Room Level 18 through 20 += 10 points per kill

etc...

Comment: floor(level/3)+4

Comment: What `floor()` are you using that returns with a remainder?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this Helps You , your First steps do not comply with any sequential Rule,So i exclude the first condition.

```
 KILL_REWARD(floor):
    ppk = 4 //Points Per Kill
    if( 1 < floor < 2)
           return ppk;
    else
         leftBound = 1 + 2;  //Firt Floor plus 2
         rightBound= 2 + 3;  //Sec Floor Plus  3
         while(!(leftBound <floor < rigthBound))
         {
             ppk += 1 ;
             leftBound += 3;
             rightBound+= 3;
         }

         return ppk;
```

Comment: Brooo, thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. Life saver :))

Comment: or U can use simply the formula @AndrewCheong has been provided!